# Why node program never terminate?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I tried to run both program using `node filename.js`, program 1 will be terminated but program 2 will not stop. It seems something is still running, am I miss-understanding something? I'm expecting program 2 will stop after processing.

**program 1**

```
function test(){
    console.log("test");
}

test();
```

**program 2**

```
var Kml = require('./kmlSchema');
var moment = require('moment');
var fs = require('fs');
var tj = require('togeojson');
// node doesn't have xml parsing or a dom. use jsdom
var jsdom =  require('jsdom').jsdom;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxx');

function readfiles(path){

    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files){

        if(err) throw err;

        files.forEach(function(file){

            fs.readFile(path+file,{encoding:'utf-8'},function(err,content){

            });
        });
    });
}

readfiles('./path/');
```

Comment: Isn't it simply because mongoose keeps the connection open? Maybe you should `disconnect`?

Comment: Can you minimalise the second program? For example, if `fs.readder`, `files.forEach` and/or `fs.readFile` are to blame, then remove `mongoose` references. Otherwise, if `mongoose` is to blame, you should be able to remove all of the `fs` and `files` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you've got a Mongoose connection that you haven't closed.

Call [`mongoose.disconnect()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-disconnect) after you've finished reading those files.

Node is an asynchronous platform and by the time the interpreter reaches the end of your code it has to make a decision about whether to close it or not. It can only safely terminate when the event loop has been cleared.

In an entirely synchronous programs no work will be added to the event loop and it will always be safe to terminate after processing the last expression. This is the case with your first program.

In your second program your call to `mongoose.connect` starts some asynchronous work that will continue to run until you explicitly call `mongoose.disconnect` to clean up the connection. Until then, it's not safe for the interpreter to terminate the program, because it doesn't know whether you've finished with the resource or not.

Comment: I came from .net, and why a database connection will stop the node to terminate the program, in .net the program will stop even I didn't close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You made a reference to .net in your comments, Node.js is different in two specific things there.

1. It was *designed* to be asynchronous. It *expects* you to have listeners, connections and similar things attached even when your code is not running. That's why *node* runtime will never close the program if it detects there are outstanding listeners.
2. With Node.js, your *code* also acts as a server, not the runtime. It means, in a typical .net, PHP etc code, you write code that is executed *per request*, while the runtime (say, IIS or whatnot) will be there in the meantime, execting new calls. So your code, when not in request, "exits".

   With Node.js, *you* write the server. You write a `require('http').listen(8080, function() {...});` So your code must always "live", be there and wait for requests.

That's, in my layman's view, the reason why Node.js code doesn't exit the program even if there's the slightest hint of an async code hooked somewhere.